# insufficient access rights on object id on CampaignMember

Tags: soap-api, campaign, campaign-member

I am updating CampaignMember status using SOAP API and it is throwing

> insufficient access rights on object id

Am using a System Admin user and it is working fine for other campaigns but failing for few.
Am able to update it manually but not via SOAP API.
Is there any Campaign specific setting?
Below is an example record

```
[40] => SObject Object
        (
            [type] => CampaignMember
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 00v1W0000262PiyQAE
                    [Status] => Active
                    [Level__c] => 0
                    [Reason__c] => 1
                    [Inactive_Date__c] => 2018-07-19T02:40:49.533Z
                )

            [id] => 00v1W0000262PiyQAE
        )

)

2018-07-18 19:40:49.6757 insufficient access rights on object id
2018-07-18 19:40:49.6763 insufficient access rights on object id
2018-07-18 19:40:49.6768 insufficient access rights on object id
```

Comment: Possibly an incorrect value being passed into a lookup field on the target object?

Comment: Don’t think so. Status is a standard picklist field on Campaign Member

Comment: This error doesn't have to do with the Status field, though. Can you show us code and an example of a record failing?

Comment: I can share the code but as I shared it is working fine for many other campaigns in the same Org, so do you think it can be the code ? I have updated the question with the record